# App to manage a football tournament database

Tags: c#, object-oriented, sql

My question is all about class design.

I have this app that is connecting to a SQL server, retrieving some tables, the user works on the data, and then it updates the database.

I should say that all that I know I learned on my own (youtube and reading) but there's still a lot of stuff that makes me confused though.

So for what I have seen, the best approach for my project is to create a class that encapsulates (nice word by the way) this model I just described.

I already have a version working very fine, but the code is all merged into the interface layer. (By working very fine I mean that I can retrieve the data from the database, work on the tables, and then update the database.)

But i fell like I'm achieving this in a very rudimentary way. Now I'm trying to make it more harmonious and well designed. Trying to master my code a bit more I guess.

So here is what I am achieving now based on the "Class" theory and OOP.

Could you help me learn whether this this is good, and if I'm designing my class in the proper way?

```
// Main class that i'm trying to model in such way to be a conceptual model of my real SQL Database (FootballProject Database).
public class fp_Database
{
    // Virtual DB.
    public static DataSet DS = new DataSet();    

    // Construtor.
    public fp_Database()
    {
        DS.Tables.Add("Seassons");
        DS.Tables.Add("Countries");
        DS.Tables.Add("Tournaments");
        DS.Tables.Add("TeamsAllowed");
        DS.Tables.Add("Matches");

        Tables = new fp_Tables();
    }


    // Public Object fp_Tables containing the fp_Database tables.
    public fp_Tables Tables;

    // fp_Tables Class definition.
    public class fp_Tables
    {

        // Instantiating all the Databases tables.
        public tableMatches Matches = new tableMatches();
        public tableSeassons Seassons = new tableSeassons();
        public tableCountries Countries = new tableCountries();
        public tableTournaments Tournaments = new tableTournaments();


        // Definition of all the fp_Tables Classes.
        public class tableSeassons
        {
            public DataTable Get_Table
            {
                get
                {
                    return DS.Tables["Seassons"];
                }
            }

            public tableSeassons()
            {
                DatabaseInterface DBInterface = new DatabaseInterface();
                SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM fp.Seassons");

                DBInterface.GetTable(DS.Tables["Seassons"], CMD);
            }
        }
        public class tableCountries
        {
            public DataTable Get_Table
            {
                get
                {
                    return DS.Tables["Countries"];
                }
            }

            public tableCountries()
            {
                DatabaseInterface DBInterface = new DatabaseInterface();
                SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM fp.Countries");

                DBInterface.GetTable(DS.Tables["Countries"], CMD);
            }
        }
        public class tableTournaments
        {
            public DataTable Get_Table
            {
                get
                {
                    return DS.Tables["Tournaments"];
                }
            }

            public void Set_Filters(int Seasson, int Country)
            {
                DS.Tables["Tournaments"].DefaultView.RowFilter = "Seasson = " + Seasson + " AND Country = " + Country;
            }

            public tableTournaments()
            {
                DatabaseInterface DBInterface = new DatabaseInterface();
                SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM fp.Tournaments ORDER BY Tournament");

                DBInterface.GetTable(DS.Tables["Tournaments"], CMD);
            }
        }
        public class tableMatches
        {
            public DataTable Get_Table
            {
                get
                {
                    return DS.Tables["Matches"];
                }
            }

            public void Load_Table_By_Tournament(int TournamentID)
            {
                DatabaseInterface DBInterface = new DatabaseInterface();
                SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM fp.Matches WHERE Tournament = " + TournamentID);

                DS.Tables["Matches"].Clear();
                DBInterface.GetTable(DS.Tables["Matches"], CMD);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
// DATA ACCESS LAYER. (SELECT - INSERT - UPDATE - DELETE)
class DatabaseInterface
{
    // Latter i will learn how to save the connection string into app.config file and read from int too.    
    private SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-8MGVKID\\MSSQLSERVER2016;Initial Catalog=FootballProject;Integrated Security=True");


    // Select Method.
    public void GetTable (DataTable Table, SqlCommand SQLCommand)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(SQLCommand.CommandText, Conn);

        Conn.Open();
        DA.Fill(Table);
        Conn.Close();
    }

    // Here will be Insert Method

    // Here will be Update Method.

    // Here will be Delete Method
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Class names should be PascalCase and should not contain non-alphanumeric characters, so `fp_Database` breaks those rules.

`tableMatches` etc. also break the PascalCase rule.

Methods shouldn't contain non-alphanumeric characters either; `Get_Table` breaks this rule.

Parameters should be camelCase, so for instance `Seasson` and `Country` as used in `Set_Filters(int Seasson, int Country)` violate this rule.

Local variables like `DBInterface` as used below should be camelCase:

```
        public tableCountries()
        {
            DatabaseInterface DBInterface = new DatabaseInterface();
            SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM fp.Countries");

            DBInterface.GetTable(DS.Tables["Countries"], CMD);
        }
```

---

You have a spelling error: `"Seassons"`. However, what's worse is that you repeatedly use this string instead of setting it as a `const` and using that. Same for other strings.

---

But the above are merely minor flaws. That they're omni-present is however a warning sign (as well as the obviously copy-pasted parts), and I'm afraid that I don't see any value in this code.

I fear you're relying on very outdated documentation; instead look into ORMs like Entity Framework and how those are used.